# "react-app-polyfill" doesn't work in IE11

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-11, polyfills

My React App is not working on IE 11.
My client wants the app to work on at least ie11.
So, i have to solve this error.

I tried the official documentation from "react-app-polyfill". But it still doesn't work.
Please help me.

**src/index.jsx**

```js
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

**package.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.25",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.24",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.4",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.5",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.3",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "npm": "^6.13.4",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-hotkeys": "^2.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.4"
  },
...
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "ie 11",
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps the issue is related to the `react-scripts version`, you are using react-scripts 3.3.0 and higher. You could check the package.json file to verify it.

There are some thread reports this error in GitHub, you could refer to them, for example: [github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8197](http://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8197), [github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8195](http://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8195).

As a workaround, you could try to downgrade the react-scripts version. As far as I know, it can still work with `react-scripts@3.2.0`.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8197#issuecomment-694454345 here he used 3.4.3 and that worked for me also

Answer (score 2):

After adding `react-app-polyfill` in your `index.js`, it will work for PROD env but you need to update your `browserslist` inside `package.json` for DEV env

**index.js**

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie9';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
.
.
```

**package.json**

```
.
.
"browserslist": {
  "production": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "development": [
    "last 1 chrome version",
    "last 1 firefox version",
    "last 1 safari version",
    "not dead" // new line
  ]
},
.
.
```

Comment: To me worked locally by updating to: "development": [  ">0.2%", "not dead" ]. Basically same as production. 
PS: using 'react-scripts 5.0.0' and 'react-app-polyfil 3.0.0'.